# Analytics Filter Report by Language

Tags: experience-analytics

I'm trying to extend the filtering options of sitecore analytics report. I've noticed that Sitecore out of the box provides filtering by Site as seen on the screenshot below. I'm using Sitecore 8.2 update 2.

[image]

I would like to recreate this dropdown to filter by language. Is there an out of the box feature for this? A configuration? Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your screenshot, it seems that you want to identify and report on "Internal search keywords" by language?

We had the same challenge for a client and the solution we came up with is, that we are writing the search queries to xDB by always using the visitor's currently displayed culture as a prefix.

**Example:**
instead of `riz` you would have `en-us;riz` etc.

This allows, if you are able to export data from xDB for internal search (for example using the [Experience Extractor](https://github.com/Sitecore/experience-extractor) module) you could parse them as CSV in Excel and thus report internal search keywords by language/culture.

Here's an example how this could look in Experience Analytics in Sitecore:

[image]

We came to this solution once we realised, that Sitecore xDB facets for internal search keywords doesn't allow adding more facets such as language/culture for an additional dimension. Thus I also think you will hit a limit for customizing the Experience Analytics interface in this regards, but in case you come up with such a UI based solution, I'd be also very interested in knowing :)

Comment: Yes, I wanted to sort the internal search by which language it came from. Thanks also for suggesting this solution, this was also what I was leaning on to if I don't find a way to create a filter. I'm currently trying to create a new segment from the internal search keyword dimension with this [link](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/create-a-custom-report-filter-and-segment.html) but it seems to not work for me.